# AttributeError: 'obj_2' object has no attribute 'var_1' - getattr -

Tags: python-3.x

I need to get data to second class from first class.
I Used - getattr - function to do it.

```
class obj_1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_1 = 'Hello'
        self.var_2 = 'World'


    def get_id(self):
        i = self.var_1
        j = self.var_2       
        return i, j

    def vw(self):
        print('Hello..')

class obj_2:
    def __init__(self):
        pass


    def r_data(self):
        print('called r_data')
        x, y = getattr(obj_1, "get_id")(self)

        print('x > ', x)
        print('y > ', y)

    def rd(self):
        getattr(obj_1, 'vw')(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ob = obj_2()
    ob.r_data()
```

It given error as - AttributeError: 'obj_2' object has no attribute 'var_1'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are getting this error since the function `get_id` uses attributes of the class, i.e `self.var_1` `self.var_2`

and these attributes  are never initialized since the `__init__` function was never called (and since you cant have attributes without an actual  object )

so to fix your code I would create an object of "obj_1" and call the function
"get_id"  with that object

```
class obj_1:
    def __init__(self):
        self.var_1 = 'Hello'
        self.var_2 = 'World'


    def get_id(self):
        i = self.var_1
        j = self.var_2
        return i, j

    def vw(self):
        print('Hello..')

class obj_2:
    def __init__(self):
        self.o1 = obj_1()


    def r_data(self):
        print('called r_data')
        x, y = self.o1.get_id()

        print('x > ', x)
        print('y > ', y)

    def rd(self):
        getattr(obj_1, 'vw')(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ob = obj_2()
    ob.r_data()
```

hope i could help, please let me know in the comments if you didn't understand anything.
and if my comment helped you i would relly appreciate marking this comment as the answer :)

Comment: My programme is run correctly with this answer. sir, but I have some question. I actually defined this two classes in two python files. so It gave me the same error message !

Comment: what is the error message that you got?

Comment: i = self.var_1               
AttributeError: 'obj_2' object has no attribute 'var_1'

Comment: could it be that the line `i = self.var_1` is un the body of the class `obj_2`?

Comment: The codding part is on first file  ( i = self.var_1). But I run the second file.

Comment: It's on -get_id- function

Comment: It's related to the class obj_1